# Can you edit the keywords for the emoji picker in Mojave?

Tags: internationalization, emoji

**TL;DR**: Is there any way to edit the keywords for the emojis that show up in the character picker?

In the emoji-picker on Mojave (10.14.3) the keywords for filtering/selecting emoji via <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd> typing and hitting <kbd>Enter</kbd> (described in [this thread](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/315031/43324)) seem to have changed — e.g.  is no longer present if you type `joy` (which is both in the literal emoji description, *and* happens to be the keyword on Slack, various other iOS keyboards etc.).

The emoji is still described as "face with tears of joy" in the emoji picker and character viewer:
[image: character viewer: face with tears of joy]

But, if you type "joy" you get the joystick emoji. I thought it might be that the emoji name had to *begin* with the typed keyword, but "HEXAGRAM FOR THE JOYOUS LAKE" still shows up:
[image: "joy" emojis in character picker]

To get , you have to type `laugh` (or some variant thereof):
[image: laugh emoji in character picker]

Is there any way to edit the keywords for the emoji that show up in the character picker?